# Twitter API in R - Follower Count by Geo

Tags: r, api, twitter, httr

I am using the twitteR package in R to extract the followerCount for twitter handles.

Is there a way to answer the question - How many followers for this twitter handle are US based?

Below is my current code:

```
library(twitteR)
follower<-getUser("@JonnyBones")
follower$followersCount
2104491
```

I want to add a filter that is something like, geo="USA"

Comment: with [rtweet](https://rtweet.info/) package using ```get_followers``` & then you apply to the result the function ```lookup_users``` & a filter on the geo information. I think you need a google api to get the exact position!  if you don't have you can still get some information on the country etc if ppl filled it on twitter

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it now! Will the rate limit be an issue if I am doing it in bulk? For example, if the amount of followers is 2MM, I would have to extract 2MM follower ids or handles, and then look up the geo for 2MM followers.

Comment: I am also doing this for 500 twitter handles

Comment: I think it will take some time, I've never try request that big using rtweet but it should do the job!

Comment: ok thank you! Appreciate the help, will let you know if I have trouble with this